# The system has data from both old+new conventions. Please use civicrm.settings.php to set civicrm.files explicitly

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, core, logs

trying to debug some other issues post-upgrade i happened to find this warning in the log repeatedly:

```
[warning] The system has data from both old+new conventions. Please use civicrm.settings.php to set civicrm.files explicitly.
```

yes, this installation is running a while now and was upgraded several times, lately with some issues. but as long as i remember i've (actively) never used or changed anything else but civicrm.settings.php

so, **question:** what is this 'old convention'? is it a different place where settings had been put or a different format used? unfortunately there's nothing to find for this error (that's why i put it in the subject)

(fwiw - right now i'm on core 5.44 with wordpress 5.8.2, everything greenlight on the status page of civicrm except for 'Resource URLs: Make them portable' and 'MySQL Emoji Support')

thanks for pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have files under both wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ and wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm (or somewhere other than uploads). Either remove one or set it in civicrm.setting.php with

```
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.files']['path'] = ...
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.files']['url'] = ...
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer. indeed i had a plugins/files/ - but it's been empty.

what baffles me a bit - how would civicrm know about this other files if their location isn't set anywhere?

Comment: also - looking into this a bit more i realize i had this warning 21 times within 5 seconds last night - but never before or after (at least in the current log-file which starts november 1st)

Comment: It knows because it used to be the default location. For timing, how often do you upgrade - the warning is a little over a year old.

Comment: well, i upgraded from 5.28 to 5.44 yesterday, couple of hours before these 21 warnings were logged .. might this have been 21 upgrades triggering this warning later on?

Comment: Makes sense, and/or cache clears during the upgrade  rebuilding things.